# PowerShell script - Sign pdf with Certificate

Tags: powershell, pdf, certificate, acrobat

I hve been working on a powershell script convert some documents to pdf and email them automatically.
This works fine. The only thing that I am missing is signing the pdf with and existing certificate.
I can manually sign the pdfs if I go to Tools Certificates > Open > Digital Sign > Draw in the pdf the desired position for the signature > Save it at a designated location.

Is there any away to perform this digital sign with certificate with a powershell script ?[PDF Certificate example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPvPf.png)

I really didn't find any solution that could perform what I need.

Comment: Please add some code example included in the questrion for a minimal viable executable example to troubleshoot.